# Error Parsing requests to JSON with Python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am trying to get the values from a request.body and parse it as a json.

For that, this is my code:

```
def checkifaddtocelery(request):
print(request.body)
body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
print(body_unicode)
body = json.loads(body_unicode)
print(body)
conid = json.dumps(body)
print(conid)
```

The error i get is this one:

```
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

And those are the prints I made:

```
b'fb_id=3911528912250446&nombre=Jonathan&appellidos=Prieto%20Abasolo&imagenperfil=https%3A%2F%2Fplatform-lookaside.fbsbx.com%2Fplatform%2Fprofilepic%2F%3Fpsid%3D2730098460446930%26width%3D1024%26ext%3D1596402069%26hash%3DAeSRFaudV025uJEJ&numdocumento=70314475'
fb_id=3911528912250446&nombre=Jonathan&appellidos=Prieto%20Abasolo&imagenperfil=https%3A%2F%2Fplatform-lookaside.fbsbx.com%2Fplatform%2Fprofilepic%2F%3Fpsid%3D2730098460446930%26width%3D1024%26ext%3D1596402069%26hash%3DAeSRFaudV025uJEJ&numdocumento=70314475
```

Comment: Your body seem to be form encoded, not json.

Comment: what is `request.headers['Content-Type']`